# Definir largura de <tr> ou <td> no HTML5

Tags: html, css

Preciso definir a largura de uma coluna em uma `table`, mas o `width` (`inline`) no HTML5 não é suportado, conforme a documentação: [HTML  Tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_td.asp)

Neste caso, não pode ser feito `inline` ? Quais as opções ?

Como em e-mail marketing, tudo deve ser `inline`, e agora !?

Comment: Sem problemas meu jovem, agora ficou mais fácil de entender mesmo rss. Já até editei minha resposta com a sua solução. Se vc quiser trabalha com um CSS externo vc tb pode, depois usa um compilador que pega seu css e coloca direto nas tag como eu fiz no exemplo. Aqui mesmo tem uma ferramente online que ajuda nisso, ela pega seu .css e coloca na tag pra vc no arquivo inteiro. http://divtable.com/table-styler/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT:**

Para fazer o estilo direto na tag vc pode usar o `style=""` para colocar o `width`

Vai ficar dessa forma:

```html
<table border="1">
      <tr>
        <td style="width:100px">100px</td>
        <td style="width:200px">200px</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

---

RBZ acredito que nesse link a fonte se refere ao `width` direto na tag tipo:

```
<td width="100px"> isso é errado mesmo!
```

Repare que todos os atributos do link são de propriedades da tag `<td>` como `colspan`, `nowrap`, `align` etc. Isso não se refere ao `width` do CSS!

Palavras da documentação da Mozilla: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table

> **Usage Note:** Do not use this attribute, as it has been deprecated. The rules should be defined and **styled using CSS**. Use the **`width`** property instead.

**Ou seja, use o `width` pelo CSS.** Como no exemplo abaixo.

```css
.gg {
  width: 100px;
}
.ggg {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td class="gg">100px</td>
    <td class="ggg">200px</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

Só um adendo, prefira pegar referências direto no
[https://www.w3.org/](https://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-html5-20100624/) ou no
https://developer.mozilla.org
são mais confiáveis

Voltando à sua dúvida, por que não usar o `css`? O atributo `width` é totalmente suportado pelo elemento `TD`. O `HTML5` não incentiva a usar esses atributos nas tags, veja o elemento `font` que foi descontinuado, tudo isso para focar estilos onde deve ser, no `CSS`

Veja esse exemplo de como usar no `CSS` de forma simples:

```css
table { border-collapse: collapse;}
th, td { border: solid 1px; padding: 0 }
td:first-child { width: 200px  }
td:first-child + td {  width: 150px }
td:first-child + td + td {  width: 120px }
```

```html
<table>
      <tr>
          <th>Primeira 200px</th>
          <th>Segunda 150px</th>
          <th>Terceira 120px</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>texto</td>
          <td>texto</td>
          <td>texto</td>
      </tr>
  </table>
```

Note que usei o seletor `first-child + td` para aplicar um estilo diferente para cada `td` em sequencia da tabela.

Comment: Não que a w3schools seja uma excelente fonte. Mas nesse caso o problema acho que não foi a fonte, mas sim o entendimento do conteúdo da página. Lá fala *"All layout attributes are removed in HTML5."* removidos do HTML5 não do CSS.

Comment: Não deixa de ser uma verdade, que o `HTML5` descontinuou os atributos de format nas *tags*, mas por isso não gosto muito da referência do w3schools :)
O w3.org por sua vez é muito detalhado e difícil de ler às vezes, por isso prefiro o mozilla.org, e ainda tem muita coisa em português. Mas concordo com você, que a forma como foi escrito lá não é bem clara

Comment: Tb uso mais a referência da MDN do que W3C, mas o w3school tem alguns exemplos práticos que as vezes ajudam o entendimento. []´s

Comment: Desculpa aí pessoal, eu que não expressei direito. Minha questão é específica do estilo na tag. Já editei a pergunta !

Comment: Entendi @RBZ, nesse caso só usar a `style: width` na tag. O negócio do `HTML5` foi remover só os atributos de estilo, como `width` e `height` mas style é totalmente funcional